# Spotfire: Some part of the data table "sp_XXXX" could not be loaded. A data source may be missing or has been changed

Tags: spotfire

I have created a spotfire visualization and saved it . However when it is tried accessing through web link I am getting below error

Some part of the data table "XXXXxxxxx" could not be loaded. A data source may be missing or has been changed.
[image]

I have done below settings :

1) The data is loaded as "Linked to source".
2) Data connections Properties -->Data connections Settings -->data Source--> --> Credentials--> credentials is given (Profile credentials has been shared)
3) I have used an Stored procedure and it is been created under the database which has spotfire access (including schema).

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using impersonation?

Comment: No. I am not using Impersonation..

Comment: What version of Spotfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved . This is due to the temp tables used in the query, it acts weirdly when the temp table used in the stored procedure (as per my observation)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you accessed the DXP via a web link, which suggests to me that you are using WebPlayer. WebPlayer will not have access to files that are stored locally. WebPlayer will load data remotely using database connections and Information Links, however.

I assume that the data load properly when you load the analysis using the desktop client?

A workaround would be to save a copy of the file for access in WebPlayer and select "Stored Data" (i.e. embedded) in the "Change all applicable data sources to:" dropdown.

Comment: Yes I am using Web Player.data also loaded properly without any issue, I works fine if used the thick client file, only issue with web player, And If i choose embedded data new data from the source wont be updated. But i need data to be updated as and when the table updates. Anyways it seems like Issue with temp Table defined in stored procedure,The temp table works fine in SQL but spotfire says undefined.